# How do I defog the windows on a older truck

Tags: ford, pick-up

My truck has no heater or A/C. Recently it's been unusually damp and foggy where I live. So now other than wiping the Windows down with a towel, I'm not sure what to do. The truck I'm driving is a 68 ford. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I thought we had a duplicate, but can't find it, so here is what I have successfully used:

- Thoroughly clean the inside of the windscreen
- Dry with paper towels
- Use a product like Rain-X anti-fog (there are various by different manufacturers, but this is what I use)

That will at least clear the windscreen. Now, to help stop it fogging up again you have some challenges.

In general, trying to keep the air cool and dry is your best bet, but without ac you can't fully do this. At best, try having windows open a little when driving - this will stop buildup of condensation from your breath.

Comment: Rory's answer is about as good of an answer as you can have in this situation. The biggest problem here is the lack of heater. You could at least get away with it. If the weather is ever below freezing, you are in serious dog-poop. Your breath will freeze to the inside of the wind shield, which is way tough to get cleared.

Answer (score 2):

I recently heard you can fill a stocking or a sock with kitty litter and it will keep the moisture absorbed. At walmart you can get silica gel crystals by the pound, or maybe it's dessicant.